# ERROR TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of 'object null' as it is null in Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having error on load of my component. I am getting this error. But once I refresh the page the error is not showing again.

This is my code:

```
loadUserSuccess = ({ data }) => {
    if (data) {
      this.user = data;

      var currentDate = new Date();
      var endDuration = new Date(this.user.endDuration);
      var hasValidExpiryDate = false;

      if (!!this.user && this.user.active) {

        currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0,);
        endDuration.setHours(0,0,0,0,);

        hasValidExpiryDate = endDuration >= currentDate;

        if (hasValidExpiryDate) {
          this.userService.goAdmin(true);
          this.userService.setAdminRole(this.user.role);
          this.menu.push({title: 'Admin', link: '/user/admin'});

          localStorage.setItem('isAdmin', 'admin');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And my error says.

[image]

I am having this error intermittently. Not every time.

And I am calling the function like this.

```
loadUser() {
  this.enjoyerService.getCmsUserByEmail(this.authService.getUser())
    .pipe(
      take(1),
    )
    .subscribe(
      this.loadUserSuccess,
      this.loadUserError,
    );
}
```

Comment: Sounds like what you are passing to 'loadUserSuccess' is null

Comment: But when I refresh it it turns out to be okay.

Comment: You should add the function call

Comment: I updated the question I am calling the function in the subscription